# Cannot use MonoTouch in Portable libraries in Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I installed Xamarin & XamarinStudio on Win7 x64 and I am able to build and test (on emu) basic android apps.

But when I'm trying to create C# Portable Class Library there is no checkbox for Android or iOS. Screenshot attached.

[image]

Could you help please?

Comment: Xamarin Studio on Windows does not support iOS.  Either use Visual Studio with the Xamarin plugin, or Xamarin Studio on a Mac for iOS support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/introduction_to_portable_class_libraries/ - use instructions from this article, particularly I needed to run PortableLibraryTools.exe /buildmachine with the Command Prompt and then reinstall the whole Xamarin.